# apk installation error : INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT

Tags: android, apk, dalvik

I am getting following error while installing apk on device:

```
10-03 20:17:35.012: I/PackageManager(11692): Running dexopt on: package name
10-03 20:17:35.932: E/dalvikvm(19729): outsSize (9) > registersSize (8)
10-03 20:17:35.932: E/dalvikvm(19729): Trouble with item 904 @ offset 0x33174
10-03 20:17:35.932: E/dalvikvm(19729): Swap of section type 2001 failed
10-03 20:17:35.932: E/dalvikvm(19729): ERROR: Byte swap + verify failed
10-03 20:17:35.971: E/dalvikvm(19729): Optimization failed
10-03 20:17:36.001: W/installd(39): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/packagename-1.apk' --- status=0xff00, process failed
10-03 20:17:36.001: E/installd(39): dexopt failed on '/data/dalvik-cache/data@app@package-1.apk@classes.dex' res = 65280
```

Comment: This is failing some static verification checks in the VM.  Was the DEX file created with the stock version of "dx"?

Comment: what do you mean by stock version of "dx"?

Comment: I'm asking if you're generating the DEX file in some unusual way, i.e. using tools other than unmodified versions of javac, dx, and so on.  If not, what version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: I am generating one dex file by combining two dex files using dx tool.

Comment: I think there are some known issues with dex merging, e.g. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40409 .  Not sure if you're being affected by something like this, but if you can avoid the merge step I'd start with that.

Comment: Yes, it is dex merging issue. I did jar merging , then created a dex file, created dex is working fine.